# error: expected type 'type' -- while trying to return error from an error set

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, set, unions, zig

I'm new to Zig and am trying to learn how error-handling and error sets work.
If I run

```
const erro = error{Oops};
fn failingFunction() erro.Oops!void {
    return erro.Oops;
}

test "returning an error" {
    failingFunction() catch |err| {
        try expect(err == erro.Oops);
        return;
    };
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: expected type 'type', found 'erro'
fn failingFunction() erro.Oops!void {
                         ^
./test.zig:45:31: note: referenced here
fn failingFunction() erro.Oops!void {
                              ^
./test.zig:50:5: note: referenced here
    failingFunction() catch |err| {
```

But when i use `erro!void` instead of `erro.Oops!void` as the funtion return type, the tests pass. Why is this so?
Please help. How do error unions work in the language? Thank You.

EDIT: The above is a modified function. The original function is

```
fn failingFunction() error{Oops}!void {
    return error.Oops;
}
```

from this article: https://ziglearn.org/chapter-1/ in the "Errors" section. I wanted to experiment and so out of curiosity I did the above.

Answer (score 1):

in `failingFunction` exception you have passed an error option (`Oops`) not error type. that's useless and wrong. overwrite your function with:

```rs
fn failingFunction() erro!void {
    return erro.Oops;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the return type must be the error set identifier, that way i can specify and return any one of the errors in the set. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: That's it: when you specify the return *type,* at comptime, you have to give an error set (something of the form `error { Oops }` (or a reference to one, like your `erro`). `erro.Oops` is, instead, a literal value which belongs to an error set, and that's what you assign to variables or return from functions at runtime.